# JSON parsing functions in BlackBerry browser

Tags: javascript, json, blackberry

If I have a web page with some Javascript code that calls the JSON parsing functions (JSON.parse and JSON.stringify), will it work in the BlackBerry browser without the help of any 3rd-party libraries? Which versions support those functions?

I looked on Google, Stack Overflow, Can I Use, and QuirksMode.org and I couldn't find anything useful about this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dead-sure that your JSON is clean and non-dangerous, just use `eval()`.

If you must parse it and your target OS version does not include JSON support (for example, the OS 6 browser does not), then you will have to resort to a third-party library.

I've been successfully using [Douglas Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: I know that I can parse JSON using eval() but I would like something safer. I know about json2.js but I am wondering if there is any need for it.

Comment: BTW, thanks for pointing out that the OS 6 browser doesn't include JSON support.

Comment: @mikez302: I know that `eval()` is frowned upon. I'd say it's safe to use as long as you tightly control the JSON you create. A minified version of `json2.js` is very light-weight (I've used the [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to compress it, it yields code that is 1.2KB when gzipped), so maybe you're too cautious about it.

Comment: Does anyone here know if the OS 7 browser has JSON support?